# Explain how to show json object from a restcontroller method using fullcalendar.js

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-boot

For this repository:
https://github.com/metronome12/boot-calendar

Somebody could explain how to relate the output of the methods in `EventController` and the `.html` file with contain a  calendar `fullcalendar.js` to show.

For example, `/events` return a JSON object but I can't see how to represent in the file `calendar.html`

And if I want a file called `mycustomcalendar.html`, how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you check the GitHub page you linked? What isn't clear about the fully detailed explaination you can find there?

Comment: Yes, I checked the github. I created my own springboot from scratch and returns json objects. In EventController /events return a json object and with page is showed?. I can only show the data in my page